# Getting error when using the SubSonicRepository update method - SubSonic 3.4

Tags: c#, subsonic3, repository

Here is sample code which I used to update customer table.

public void UpdateCustomer() {

```
   SAPDB db = new SAPDB();
   SubSonicRepository<Customer> ssr = new SubSonicRepository<Customer>(db);
   Customer customer = new Customer();
   customer.ID = 5;
   customer.CustomerName = "John";
   int val = ssr.Update(customer);
```

}

Please let me know the way I am following is right or wrong? or Is it a error in SubSonic 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is your schema?

You might want to load your customer's existing data by doing

```
Customer c= new Customer(5);
customer.CustomerName = "John";
customer.Save();
```

Comment: I tried your code using MS SQL Server as a back end and it was working fine :( Maybe you do not have your primary key set as an identity? What is the error message you are getting?